# error in FactoryGirl when trying to create objects before another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I am trying to create a model named global_list. It will take a list which is associated with a user and a global_id which is associated with an item. I need to create a user (a list is created in a callback for this object) and an item (where a global_identification is created as a callback to item creation). Neither of the following solutions work in trying to create these associated objects before. Should they? Is there a better way to handle this? I have tried creating accessors for liked_item_list_id but that also didn't work.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :global_list do
    before(:create) {
       user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)
       mi=FactoryGirl.create(:item)
    }
    list_id user.liked_list_id
    global_id mi.global_id
  end
end
```

Will a block help?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :global_list do
    before(:create) {
      user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      mi=FactoryGirl.create(:item)
    }

    list_id { List.first.id }
    global_id { 3 } # 3 will be created at this point { mil.global_id } doesn't work
  end
end
```

I'm starting to think this is not possible with FactoryGirl. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :global_list do
    list_id { FactoryGirl.create(:user).liked_list_id }
    global_id { FactoryGirl.create(:item).global_id }
  end
end
```

Ruby's blocks in this context are confusing. So I asked: [what's the practical difference between these two FactoryGirl declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371480/whats-the-practical-difference-between-these-two-factorygirl-declarations)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :global_list do
        before(:create) { |list|
           user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)
           mi=FactoryGirl.create(:item)
           list.list_id = user.liked_list_id
           list.global_id = mi.global_id
        }
      end
    end
```

Its completely untested

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible in FactoryGirl, and actually often used.

It's simple to define associated object in a factory like below. No fancy "before" needed.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :global_list do
    user
    mi
    foo_attribute
    bar_attribute
  end

  factory :user do
    # blah
  end

  factory :mi do
    # blah
  end
end
```

With above code, FactoryGirl will create required associated object at first and use their id to create this object automatically.

Comment: hmm... so that sounds right BUT I am returning this list via  `user.liked_items_list.id`; I have an attr_reader for liked_items_list  but I get an error `/Users/jt/repos/src/spec/factories.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `liked_items_list' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x007fe516999c80> (NoMethodError)`; I know this is getting pretty specific but ...

Comment: unfortunately, I seem to have to pass back the object and assign it to the value

Comment: Please list all involved models with association code, and the steps you can do in console or in real code to reach your goal.

Comment: thx Billy, I think I probably asked the question poorly. It's a bit of a complex model relationship where I create a proxy object in a callback. I have asked a second question to try to help clarify it in my head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371480/whats-the-practical-difference-between-these-two-factorygirl-declarations